# How to set a value in a particular cell in google sheets using apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

[image: Sample image for my question]

I have a google sheet with a table including **City Name** and **Code** as headings. You can see it in the image that I've attached.

I have to use a lot of repetitive city names for this table for some reason. So I need to make a function to select a selection from City name (from any where in 'A' cell) and replace the relevant city code in the **Code** cell 'B'(in front of the relevant city name) if you can please help me to figure this out. Sorry for my bad English. I`m still learning it as a second language.

city code ex: NY, TK , DL

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your sample image, I cannot understand `a function to select a selection from City name (from any where in 'A' cell) and replace the relevant city code in the Code cell 'B'(in front of the relevant city name)`. Can I ask you about the detail of the current issue of your script and your goal? And also, can you provide your current script and the detail of current issue of your script?

Comment: You're looking for [tag:vlookup]

Answer (score 1):

```
function ezfunk() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('sheetname');
  const vs = sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1, 2).getDisplayValues();
  let vc = vs.map(r => [`${r[1]},${r[0]}`]);
  sh.getRange(2,3,vc.length,vc[0].length).setValues(vc);
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(vc));
}
```

Comment: Does the code make sense? Did you try it? It produces this: https://imgur.com/Disvz7g.png

Answer (score 0):

You can use a formula. Try to paste this formula into `B3` cell:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFS(A3:A="NEW YORK","NY",A3:A="TOKYO","TK",A3:A="DEHLI","DL",A3:A="",""))
```